# NoSuchMethodError Java Commons.Net setCopyStreamListener

Tags: java, nosuchmethod

im getting the following error, when I want to execute my Java program:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient.setCopyStreamListener(Lorg/apache/commons/net/io/CopyStreamListener;)V
    at PzFtpUpload.<init>(PzFtpUpload.java:77)
    at Javatest.<init>(Javatest.java:29)
    at Javatest.main(Javatest.java:602)
```

And here is my constructor, where I need to set the CopyStreamListener with an override.

```
public PzFtpUpload() {

    ftps = new FTPSClient("TLS"); // SSL/TLS ggf zu einem späteren zeitpunkt
    ftps.setCopyStreamListener(

        new CopyStreamAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void bytesTransferred(long totalBytesTransferred, int bytesTransferred, long streamSize) {

            File uploadfile = new File(path);

               try{
                    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\lsp\\Desktop\\status.txt", "UTF-8");
                    writer.println((int)(totalBytesTransferred/uploadfile.length()) * 100);
                    writer.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                   System.out.println("Error writing status file.");
                }
        }

     });
}
```

Comment: Check your version of Apache Commons Net, this method exists since 3.0 : https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#setCopyStreamListener(org.apache.commons.net.io.CopyStreamListener)

Comment: Im working with 3.3 since the beginning of my developing.

Comment: Could you add the relevant part from `PzFtpUpload` ?

Comment: Looke above.....

Comment: Since the code compiles and the error occurs at runtime, you probably have an old version of Commons Net in the classpath when your application is running.Try  to print the result of `FTPSClient.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath()` to see which jar it comes from.

Comment: I get the following: "/C:/pz/classpath/commons-net-3.3.jar"

Comment: Otherwise, I just need a method, that writes the percentage of an upload into a text file - all I found is just the method you can see above. If there is a more simple way (without override etc) please let me know.

Comment: nobody got a hint / solution for that ?